# Getting system date in low level API 17

Tags: android

I need a way to get system date,to display in my mobile  app. Minimum API level of 17 without using calendar class.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: I found some ways to get system date.  Like simpleDateFormat(). But the getInstance() requires api 24

Comment: Ok, I have got an alternative solution. Would you like to see?

Comment: Yes....kindly write your answer...I really need it

Comment: I've added my answer. You may check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to get System Date, Time, TimeZone  :

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, currentDate.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Then **SPLIT** your string to get DATE, TIME separately:

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Its working. Once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get system date with Calendar class:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Get system date with Date class:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

All this classes are exist in API level 17 and higher.

Comment: My application's minimum API level is 17....but the getInstance() requires api 24...

Comment: You can just create new date instance with default constructor like Date date = new Date();. value of "date" gonna be the current system date.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Once again thanks